# Authentication with passport. Can I trust that req.user is indeed the logged in user?

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

I'm using [passport](http://passportjs.org/) to authenticate users at my site. Users can register orders, which have and foreignKey (ObjectId) to the User object.

Example-objects (written as mongoose schemas):

```
var orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    address: String,
    _userID: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User'}
});

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
});
```

Mongoose will create the primary key for each object.

My question is; is it enough to check if `req.user._id === order._userID`? Or can the `req.user` object be tampered with? Can I trust that `req.user._id` is the `id` of the logged in user?

I've found a couple of good resources, but it's not exactly what I'm asking of.

- http://toon.io/articles/understanding-passportjs-authentication-flow/
- http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the question:

> can the req.user object be tampered with?

Is difficult to answer, since you *could* have code within your application that will have access to your request object, and within it, modify the `user`.  It's important to understand what code you have running within the flow of each request for anyone really, but especially those concerned about the security of their application.  With that said, I can at least point you to where in the code this is established, and you can trace it with a debugger to assure yourself of the flow.

As you've mentioned, the [passport documentation discusses authentication configuration options in their guide](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/), and by default will process "logging in" the user when your strategy dictates successful authentication.  You can provide a custom callback (mentioned in the referenced documentation above) to process this as well.  In the end, it's important that `req.logIn` is called (which is done by default without any custom callbacks provided).  [Here's a link to the source](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/a06f9b239c4ffaa2cfb134a6bd13a85fbad348b5/lib/http/request.js#L8-L56).  (Passport extends the request object via this code to provide helper functions which it later uses.)

The specific line you maybe interested in is [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/a06f9b239c4ffaa2cfb134a6bd13a85fbad348b5/lib/http/request.js#L42), which assigns to the `req` object the property `user` with a value of the authenticated user:

```
this[property] = user;
```

From there on, you have access to the logged in user under `req.user`, and their ID under `req.user.id`.  Again note that this `logIn` function should only be called when the passport strategy states that successful authentication has occurred.  But in this way, passport has provided you with a way of easily authenticating the user, and then getting access to this user via the request object.