# Is verifying whether a user is an admin based on req.user secure?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am using a simple middleware function in my `express.js` app to verify whether a user has admin privileges:

```
function isAdmin (req, res, next) {
    if (req.user.admin)
        return next();
    res.redirect("/");
}
```

`passport` is being used for account authentication.

Is this secure or can `req.user.admin` be injected into the request for users who are not supposed to have admin privileges? Should I first find a user and then check whether said user has admin privileges? For example:

```
function isAdmin (req, res, next) {
    if (req.user) {
        User.findOne({ "_id" : req.user._id }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            } else if (user.admin) {
                return next();
            } else {
                res.redirect("/");
            }
        })
    } else {
        res.redirect("/");
    }
}
```

To me, this seems needlessly complicated. It would also cause more database accesses. Is this necessary to verify whether a user is truly an admin or is my first function sufficient? In essence, who can view or alter `req` and, thereby, `req.user`?

Comment: This question might be relevant to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649274/authentication-with-passport-can-i-trust-that-req-user-is-indeed-the-logged-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not terribly familiar with passport but if it is similar to how [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) works, the req.session object is stored in a (potentially encrypted) cookie and so if you build an authentication system off of this, you can store user information in req.session.user and be confident that is is secure.